# Copy values, not formulas from columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have two workbooks (source and target) and I want to copy column A in the source workbook to column A in the target workbook.
I used this code for the above.

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

But the source sheet contains cells with formulas. I just want to copy the cell values,  but not formulas.

What changes should I make to the above code?

---

```
Sub BOM()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("MASTER").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("BOM").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("MASTER").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("D")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("BOM").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("MASTER").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("E")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("BOM").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn


End Sub
```

This is the code I used to copy the cells from one workbook to another. It's working fine on my PC which is running Windows 7 Excel 2010, but I want to run the same code on PCs which are using XP Excel 2007.

I am getting `Runtime error: Subscript out of range.` while running the macro, and when I click debug button, it points to the third line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this, this is my favorite:

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()

    Dim iCopyingRow as long '-counter for which row we are copying at the moment
    Dim iLastRowToCopy as long '- lookup for last row to copy
    With  Workbooks("Source").Sheets("Sheet1")
        iLastRowToCopy = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    For iCopyingRow = 1 to iLastRowToCopy 
        Workbooks("Target").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCopyingRow ).value = _
             Workbooks("Source").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCopyingRow ).value
    Next iCopyingRow 

End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks like form your code posted below in an answer that you are trying to copy three columns. you can modify the above code to do all three columns like this:

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()

    Dim iCopyingRow as long '-counter for which row we are copying at the moment
    Dim iLastRowToCopy as long '- lookup for last row to copy
    With  Workbooks("Source").Sheets("Sheet1")
        iLastRowToCopy = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    For iCopyingRow = 1 to iLastRowToCopy 
        Workbooks("Target").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCopyingRow ).value = _
             Workbooks("Source").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & iCopyingRow ).value
        Workbooks("Target").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & iCopyingRow ).value = _
             Workbooks("Source").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & iCopyingRow ).value
        Workbooks("Target").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & iCopyingRow ).value = _
             Workbooks("Source").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & iCopyingRow ).value
    Next iCopyingRow 

End Sub
```

Comment: @Lavan Madaparambil I didnt see your comment because it was ont he other answer. Are you using my solution or his?

The above code only has three dependancies. 1- a workbook names "source", 2 - a workbook named target, 3 - a sheet named 'sheet1' in each workbook none of that is workbook specific.

Comment: you might be expierencing difficulties referencing the workbooks. Instead of using the words "target" and "Source" from yoru original code try replacing them with the full file-paths like this: "C:\testFolder\anotherfolder\target.xls" where the "C:\testfolder\anotherfolder\" is the modification to the file, and the fole extension .xls, .xlsx, or .xlsm matches the file type. (.xls is for older versions of excel)

Comment: I will try this and get back to u

Answer (score 0):

A spin on @gimp's solution. The only material change is this avoids concatenation to build the ranges.

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook2()
Dim TheRange As Range
Dim ACell As Range
  Set TheRange = Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
  For Each ACell In TheRange.Cells
    Workbooks("Target.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ACell.Address).Value = _
      Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ACell.Address).Value
  Next ACell
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx alot andy holaday and Gimp

One more problem.The macro is working fine on my pc which is running microsoft office 2010.But its not working on any other pc which is running 2007 office.
what can be the issue.

Comment: @andy holaday is there any performance reason who looping through range objects instead of looking through the row numbers would be used, or is this an aesthetic change? It seems that excel is actually referencing the sheet to look up the string vlaue of the address for each iteration of the loop which would increase references to and from the sheet thus decreasing performance. Am I wrong here? Additionally, why use the `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` instead of the fully qualified ` Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange` in regards to consistancy through the code.

Comment: Finally if the Op used your code, you're making references to the file extensions .xlsm or .xlsm which is an assumption that the OP is using 2007 / 2010 which may not be true, (and may be causing the problems in the OP's comment) I responded to your idea here of fully qualifying the workbook names to the next level with explanation as a comment above.